# NoClassDefFoundError IN Struts2 framework

Tags: java, struts2, httpclient

I am using Struts2 framework and using HttpClient class for making put request.
When I try to call httpClient's requestEntity method in LoginAction class I am getting the following error.

SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEntity

I have included all the required jar files in the class path.

Kindly help me figure out what could be the problem.

Comment: What application server or servlet container are you using? Provide a list or screenshot of the JARs that are in your WAR (or exploded directory). The exception you are getting implies that you _do not_ actually have all of the required JARs.

Comment: Use IDE for example eclipse.Ideally if LoginAction class should not compiled if httpClient class does not exist in classpath

Comment: @MSach : if he did not directly used that class, the another class(may be from other library) he is using in library may reference `RequestEntity`. This time he will not get compiler error.

Comment: @StevenBenitez I am using tomcat servlet container.                           list of jars I am using are                                                   commons-codec-1.3.jar                                                     commons-code-1.4.jar                                                       commons httpclient-3.1.jar                                                and there dependency jars

Comment: @MSach yes I am using IDE Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply.I am also getting a Deprecation warning for the class StringRequestEntity class? Inspite of adding all the jar files to the class path I am getting the same error. Kindly help.

Comment: Just because you have the HttpClient JAR included in your IDE for compilation purposes does not mean that it is being packaged in the WAR file that Tomcat is running. All signs seem to point to the JAR not being packaged as part of your WAR.

Comment: @Steven could you tell me how to package it as a WAR..The list of jars I am using are httpclient-4.0.jar
httpcore-4.0.1.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-httpclient-3.0.jar   Are there any other jar files other than these to be included here? Kindly let me know.Thank you.

Comment: You should decide which version of httpclient you're using; packaging both 3 and 4 versions could lead to various problems.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am using only version 3 but still it does not work.:(

Comment: This error exists only for classes which are implementing Interfaces.So how do I call these classes?Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using older version(  apache commons less than 3.0) then that class will not be available in old jar. You have to use `Apache commons 3.0` library. `org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEntity` class is added since `v3.0`. Check [javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEntity.html).

Generally If we do not have jar added in classpath(or not in project) then we get `ClassNotFoundException` and if we have jar included in project and it is in classpath but particular class is not available then we get `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.yes I am using the v3.0 of the jar.However,still the error persists. Please can you tell me is there any other way to make the class availaible.

Comment: open jar either in eclipse or winrar and check if class exists.

Comment: I don't think your explanation of the difference between those two exceptions is accurate. Check the Javadocs. `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that the class existed during compilation, but is nowhere to be found now. This implies to me that he is not actually deploying the JAR as part of his WAR (or exploded directory).

Comment: another situation may be : if you did not directly used that class, the another class(may be from other library) you are using in library may reference `RequestEntity`. This time you will not get compiler error but `NoClassDefFoundError` at runtime.

Comment: Please could you tell me exactly which jar is to be used to resolve this error?I am using version 3 of the jar. Or is it required to set the class path in the Manifest file? Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @Nandkumar yes the RequestEntity class exists in both 3.1 and 3.0 jar files.

Comment: @Soham : then you must be using both old and new jars. And your app is considering old jars.

Comment: I wrote a seperate method in a main class to check if the httpclient method works.It works fine independently.However,when I try to embed it in the framework it gives this error.If this is the case it shoudnt work in the main class too right?

Comment: I tried using 1 jar still it does not work.If you could provide me the exact jar I need to include it would really help me resolve the problem.Thank you.

Comment: @Soham : I told possible ways, please check it again, there might be older jars.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15351/discussion-between-nandkumar-and-soham)